# Im trying to create a replica set on mongoDB but the process to create the server runs forever and it gives me this error

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing.","nextWakeupMillis":10400}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-24T20:16:59.855+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4939300, "ctx":"monitoring-keys-for-HMAC","msg":"Failed to refresh key cache","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Cannot use non-local read concern until replica set is finished initializing."

the command i entered:
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db1 --replSet myReplicaSet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sSFn.png)

Comment: The image content is the _server log_. Here are the steps about [Deploying a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the question is actually very straightforward: how do you start up a mongo server with replica set functionality? the docs say to use the command in the question, and it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the steps mentioned for reconfigure the replicaset.

Comment: can you add links or detailed answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).